# Table formatting

Tags: tables

I am working on the table

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \ra{1.5}
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}clllclll@{}}
    \hline 
     File
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Logistic Regression}} &\phantom{abc}
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Support Vector Machine}} &\\
    \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8} 
    & sensitivity & specificity & total accuracy && sensitivity 
    & specificity & total accuracy\\ 
   \hline
   $100$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 \\
   $101$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143\\
   $102$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930\\
   $103$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764\\
   $104$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000\\
   $105$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326\\
   \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the output is [image]
I have these problems in formatting the table

1. (Done) Put a  name for the first column
2. (Done) Center the words for "logistic reg" and "support vector machine"
3. Output with very small margin like a picture.
4. Other suggestions making the table looks professional.
5. How to insert two extra columns to right of first column
6. (Done)Center "File" with respect to "logistic regression" and 'sensitivity, spe....'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ad 1.: Simply add some words between the first `\hline` and the `&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Logistic Regression}}`. Ad 2.: centre the words with respect to what? Ad 3.: what does 'like a picture' mean in this context?  Ad 4. `\usepackage{dcolumn}` and align numbers along the decimal point (or use the package `siunitx`). Also get rid of the `\phantom{abc}`. Also: why are some numbers math (`$100$`) and others 'text'.

Comment: @Jon thanks for your reply. I am not able to upload picture. And the questions  might be confusing. Q2: I want to center w.r.t. the 2 sub-columns. Q3: I would like to output the table as picture so that I can include it into my other files. And I need the output has minimum margin.

Comment: Regarding '2.': something can only be centred relative to something else; how must "logistic reg" and "support vector machine" be centred?  (that is, which columns are they to be centred over?).  Regarding '3.': do you mean put a 'frame' around the entire table? including the caption?  Can you provide a link to a table in a book that you like (say, available through Google Books)?

Comment: It looks like '1.' has been solved (based on my first comment?).

Comment: @jon YES, thanks. By the way, can I center the 'File' in the first colum?

Comment: It should already be centred: the line `\begin{tabular}{@{}clllclll@{}}` says you want the 1st and 5th columns centred and the rest left-aligned.

Comment: Hi  @jon , I mean center the word "File".

Comment: It is centred, really!

Answer (score 7):

**1. Put a name for the first column**
There is already one, namely "File". Do you want to lower it to the second line? I wouldn't, because it is hierarchically on the same level as "Logistic..." and "Support...".

**2. Center the words for "logistic reg" and "support vector machine"**
Well, those are already centered, just not on the right columns. In your code, they are each centered on the first 2 columns below the `\cline`. Change the `\multicolumn{2}` to `\multicolumn{3}` and you'll probably get what I believe you mean.

**3. Output with very small margin like a picture.**
Check the `geometry` options if you are talking about page geometry, e.g.

```
\usepackage[landscape,scale=0.95]{geometry}
```

FYI, `geometry` enables you to change the geometry of a single page and resetting the usual geometry afterwards.

**4. Other suggestions making the table looks professional.**
Use the `caption` package to correct spacing for table captions: while table captions should be placed before the (tabular) content (as you did) and picture captions should be placed after the image, by default LaTeX puts vertical space before the caption label and not after it.

Use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package (that you are loading without using) instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

Given that you are displaying figures meant to be compared, make the comparison easy to the eye: align your columns containing said figures right, in order to align the decimals. For even better results, use the `dcolumn` package as in [jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon)'s answer to automatically align the figures on their decimal and format them correctly (including using a *minus* sign instead of a *hyphen*). FYI, you can use the `siunitx` package in the rest of your document to format numbers (with `\num`) and units (with `\si`), but their use in `tabular`s is rather tedious. Also, for easy readability, units should go in your `tabular`'s head, not inside the data itself.

Remove the unnecessary `@{}` and extra middle column; unless you know exactly what and why, (La)TeX does its typesetting pretty well on its own :)

Remove the `\arraystretch` / `\ra` "trick".

Given the "File" heading is structurally at the same level as the two "Regression" ones, use the same font for it. Also, put all your headings with a capital (or none, but be coherent).

Finally, to ease your own coding, I would suggest you format the content of your tabular with white spaces to visually separate the columns and resemble your output. I've found that editing tabulars made this way is much more easy, especially when you have to modify documents a few weeks / months after their creation.

**Putting it all together**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{4}}% column type for figures with 4 decimals
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}% to format sub-headings of d-type columns
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{tabular}{cd{4}d{4}d{4}d{4}d{4}d{4}}
    \toprule 
    \textbf{File}&                       \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Logistic Regression}}&                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Support Vector Machine}}\\
    \cmidrule(rl){2-4} \cmidrule(rl){5-7} 
                 & \subhead{Sensitivity}& \subhead{Specificity}& \subhead{Total accuracy}& \subhead{Sensitivity}& \subhead{Specificity}& \subhead{Total accuracy}\\ 
    \midrule
         100     &                0.0790&                0.1692&                   0.2945&                0.3670&                0.7187&                    3.1815\\
         101     &             -  0.8651&               50.0476&                   5.9384&             -  9.0714&              297.0923&                   46.2143\\
         102     &              124.2756&             - 50.9612&                 -14.2721&              128.2265&             -630.5455&                 -381.0930\\
         103     &                0.0357&                1.2473&                   0.2119&                0.3593&             -  0.2755&                    2.1764\\
         104     &             - 17.9048&             - 37.1111&                   8.8591&             - 30.7381&             -  9.5952&                 -  3.0000\\
         105     &              105.5518&              232.1160&                 -94.7351&              100.2497&              141.2778&                 -259.7326\\
   \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image: Result]

Comment: I think there is also something to be said for making the negative numbers not use a (text) hyphen.

Comment: Can I center the word "File" with respect to the "logistic regression" and "sensitivity..."?

Comment: @jon Yes, I considered throwing `siunitx` in there...

Comment: @Lerong I don't get what you mean: "File" is centered above its column, which I guess contains the number of the file. Where else would you want it?

Comment: @Xavier I mean both horizontally and vertically centered. thanks.

Comment: @Lerong Oh... For that, have a look at `\multirow`. But I refuse to put such a bad example in my answer: it will only make your table harder to read. When your eyes scan a table, they mostly do it row by row (sometimes column by column). So centering cells vertically, while made popular by Excel and Word, is actually counter-productive from an eye efficiency point of view (your eyes need to go up and down looking for the line, which is distracting). It would also destroy the visual hierarchy in your case.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks very much for your helpful solution.

Comment: @Lerong You're welcome. I just added the use of `siunitx` and `\num` to format figures, to solve the minus vs hyphen issue that jon mentioned.

Comment: @Lerong I've now swapped `dcolumn` in place of `siunitx`, which is way less tedious for `tabular`s.

Answer (score 5):

To a large degree, tables are a matter of taste.  But I think this is true to the posted image, but a little tider in presentation.  Although you loaded `booktabs`, you aren't using it (but I agree you should); the same goes for `multirow` (which would serve no purpose in this table, anyway); I don't see what benefit accrues from setting `\arraystretch` to 1.5; and I still don't understand why you want only some numbers as 'math'.  So, as a start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{4}}
\newcommand{\mlc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
%  \ra{1.5}% <-- why?
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c d{4} d{4} d{4} d{4} d{4} d{4} @{}}
    \toprule
    File
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Logistic Regression}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Support Vector Machine}}\\
    \cmidrule(rl){2-4} \cmidrule(rl){5-7}

    & \mlc{sensitivity} & \mlc{specificity} & \mlc{total accuracy}
    & \mlc{sensitivity} & \mlc{specificity} & \mlc{total accuracy}\\
    \midrule
    $100$ & 0.0790   & 0.1692   & 0.2945   & 0.3670   & 0.7187    & 3.1815 \\
    $101$ & -0.8651  & 50.0476  & 5.9384   & -9.0714  & 297.0923  & 46.2143\\
    $102$ & 124.2756 & -50.9612 & -14.2721 & 128.2265 & -630.5455 & -381.0930\\
    $103$ & 0.0357   & 1.2473   & 0.2119   & 0.3593   &  -0.2755  & 2.1764\\
    $104$ & -17.9048 & -37.1111 & 8.8591   & -30.7381 & -9.5952   & -3.0000\\
    $105$ & 105.5518 & 232.1160 & -94.7351 & 100.2497 & 141.2778  & -259.7326\\
   \bottomrule

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You made me discover the `dcolumn` package! I used to define my own commands to format numbers separately and or use `siunitx`. I'll adapt my answer to reflect this, as it's definitely better.

Comment: @Xavier -- It's a useful, for sure!  Your attempt to produce the OP's table looks much better as a result (unfortunately, I already gave a +1 last night....)